# How can I stream MP3 with AudioTrackStreamer?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, streaming

I'm trying to create a mp3 streamer, but I'm failing miserably :-)

I've got the following in my `AudioTrackStreamer`:

```
        protected override void OnBeginStreaming(AudioTrack track, AudioStreamer streamer)
        {
            //TODO: Set the SetSource property of streamer to a MSS source
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/85085126/stream?consumer_key=db840ada2477a93d5fdbcc96a46b37c1");
            req.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            try
            {
                req.BeginGetRequestStream((callback) =>
                    {
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callback.AsyncState;
                        Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(callback);
                        Mp3MediaStreamSource src = new Mp3MediaStreamSource(stream, 1000);

                        streamer.SetSource(src);

                        NotifyComplete();

                    }, req);
            }
            catch { }
```

And it fails, catching `ProtocolIViolationException` with the message:

```
[Arg_InvalidOperationException]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.50829.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_InvalidOperationException
```

The url to the file is something I found while googling free Music, and if you open it you get to download a mp3 file... so the source should be legit?

Comment: Hi Jason94, have you been able to create a MP3 streamer with Mp3MediaStreamSource?

Answer (score 1):

1. You're using the wrong stream for the data source. Replace `[Begin/End]GetRequestStream` with `[Begin/End]GetResponse`, in the completion handler call `WebResponse.GetResponseStream` to access the correct stream.
2. Don't call `NotifyComplete` from `OnBeginStreaming`. Instead, call `NotifyComplete` when the track is played to the end.
3. Before `BeginGetResponse`, you should set `req.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;` otherwise your MP3s will download completely before playback.

Update - my while() loop looks like this:

```
while( true )
{
    if( cancel.IsCancellationRequested )
        return;

    if( buffer.hasFreeSpace() )
    {
        int cb = await this.downloadAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );
        var buffWaiter = m_bufferAwaiter;
        if( 0 == cb )
        {
            Exception ex = new Exception( "runBackgroundAsync: connection dropped" );;
            if( null != buffWaiter )
                buffWaiter.Fail( ex );
            throw ex;
        }

        if( null != buffWaiter )
        {
            // The client is waiting for the data to be pre-buffered
            if( buffWaiter.haveBuffer( buffer.cbLength ) )
            {
                // Sufficient data has been downloaded, so playback is going to resume after this haveBuffer() call.
                m_bufferAwaiter = null;
            }
        }
        continue;   //< Continuing to while(true) without a single sleep.
    }
    await TaskEx.Delay( this.tsSleepTimeWhenBufferFull, cancel ).ConfigureAwait( false );
}
```

Comment: What about seting the length at
Mp3MediaStreamSource src = new Mp3MediaStreamSource(stream, 1000); ?

Wouldn't it stop at the end of the specified length (1000)?

Comment: I've tried using Mp3MediaStreamSource, spent some time trying to fix it, but failed. I've created my own implementation of MediaStreamSource. Sorry can't help you with Mp3MediaStreamSource. Remember it's not an SDK class, it's just an open source project..

Comment: AllowReadStreamBuffering property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowreadstreambuffering(v=vs.105).aspx
The default is true. And the documentation says when its true, BeginGetResponse callback is raised once the entire stream has been downloaded into memory.
The stream of the radio is of _infinite_ length: the radio plays on and on.
Without the req.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false, the GetRequestStream callback will never be called. Instead, the application will eventually crash, with out of memory exception.

Comment: Thanks... Can you please share the part of the code where you are buffering the data to be played (in a while loop)? Do you do it in GetSampleAsync?

Comment: I have a single 512kb circular buffer. I maintain this buffer filled by a dedicated background routine. When I receive GetSampleAsync call, I usually return a portion of the data that is already downloaded earlier. See the update to my answer.

The complete code that does all that is about ~700 lines of code, highly-asynchronous (I use async-await), and I’m not going to share it unless I’m paid for that.